# Tool to determine PHP version compliance

Tags: php, version, analysis

Is there any tool that can analyze PHP code and tell if it will work or not with certain PHP versions? For example if I have code developed using PHP5.3 and want a fairly quick way to tell if it contains code that is not available in, say, PHP5.1? I am mainly thinking in terms of static analysis here.

Comment: yeah, the manual at php.net/manual

Comment: Try running it against PHP 5.2 and see if it crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [PHP_CompatInfo](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo) for this. It's outdated now, but was intended specifically for probing scripts against compatibility lists.

The new [PHP_CompatInfo 2](http://php5.laurent-laville.org/compatinfo/) with [PHP_Reflect](http://php5.laurent-laville.org/reflect/) are worth investigating however.
On Github: https://github.com/llaville/php-compat-info

Answer (score -1):

You can run a PHP server locally with the version you require and just install your software there.